# Python - Convert function return values to int in a single line

Tags: python

I wanted to convert the values that are being returned from a function to **int** in a single line but when I try I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

My code is the following:

```
def test_func():
    return 3.4, 3.5


a, b = int(test_func())

print a , b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead

```
def test_func():
    return 3.4, 3.5

a, b = map(int, test_func())

print a, b
>>> 3 3
```

`int` is a type that can be constructed from floats (`int(3.4)`), strings (`int("3")`) and other things, but each time you use it it must be to create *one* integer value; you cannot call it with two values. Instead, you have to call `int` on each value in the tuple returned by `test_func`. To do that, you can call `map` to call the `int` function on each value of the tuple. This will return a sequence (or a generator in Python 3) that will be iterated to unpack it into `a` and `b` variables, giving the wanted result.

Comment: despite of `map` returning an `iterable` in Python 3, this works there too.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, a cool thing about unpacking is that it works with iterables in general and not just sequences.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test_func():
    return 3.4, 3.5

a, b = [int(i) for i in test_func()]

print (a, b)
```